# Acid base titration curve

Tags: titration

Why we don't get sharp point at equivalence points in case of acid base titration other than the case of strong acid and strong base titration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of strong acid-strong base titration at equivalence point with the addition of very small amount of titrant (like a drop) the pH change is very large. That means the range over which indicator changes its color is likely to be passed in a drop of titrant, resulting in a sharp end point.

Whereas in the other cases the change of pH at equivalence point is less dramatic and there will be a smaller change in pH at equivalence point. So, the indicator will change its color slowly resulting in a wider end point.